# Ajax Controller Not Redirect to login page

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, controllers, ajax, redirect

I have Custom Ajax Call, If Customer not login in, then redirected to Login page. But Controller call this code, its says redirected, its not redirected.

**Reference:**

[image]

**My Code:**

```
                <?php

      namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Index;
      use Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory;

      class CustomImage extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
      {
          protected $logger;
          protected $_productRepositoryFactory;
          protected $_storeManager;
          protected $customerSession;
          protected $resultJsonFactory;


          public function __construct(
              \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
              \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $loggerinterface,
              \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
              \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterfaceFactory $productRepositoryFactory,
              JsonFactory $resultJsonFactory,
              \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager


          )
          {
              parent::__construct($context);
              $this->logger = $loggerinterface;
              $this->_productRepositoryFactory = $productRepositoryFactory;
              $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
              $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
          }

          /**
           * Execute view action
           *
           * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface
           */
          public function execute()
          {
              $this->logger->addDebug("Custom Image Block");
              try {

                  $this->logger->addDebug("try Block");
                  if ($this->customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {

                      //my code

                  } else {
                                    $response = [
                'errors' => false,
                'message' => __('Added Item successful.')
            ];
            //If not not login and check isXml Http request(Ajax)
            if(!$this->customerSession->isLoggedIn() && !$this->getRequest()->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
                $response['errors'] = true;
                $response['message'] = 'Error Here';
                $response['redirectUrl'] = $this->_url->getUrl('customer/account/login');
                /** @var \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Json $resultJson */
                $resultJson = $this->resultJsonFactory->create();
                $resultJson->setData($response);
                return $resultJson;
            }
                  }

              } catch (Exception $e) {
                  $this->messageManager->addError($e->getMessage());
              }

          }
      }
```

**My ajax.js**

```
  define(["jquery"], function ($) {
      var main =
          function (config) {
              $("#finish_design_button").on("click", function () {
                  execCommand(config);
              });
          }
      //ajax request for load docker
      function execCommand(config) {
          $.ajax({
              url: config.custom_image,
              type: 'POST',
              showLoader: true,
              dataType: 'json'
          }).done(function (response) {
              console.log(response);

              if (response.redirectUrl) {
                  window.location.href = response.redirectUrl;
              }
          });
      }
      return main;

  });
```

My Template:

```
  <script type="text/x-magento-init">
      {
          "*": {
              "Vendor_Module/js/custom_image":{"custom_image":"<?php echo $block->getUrl('greeting/index/customimage', []); ?>"}
          }
      }
      </script>
```

Now,Thorw **TypeError: response is null**.

Suggest Me, whats Wrong in my code and  how to get response from Controller.

Comment: Try after add `die();` just after redirection code.

Comment: @PrincePatel   after add die(); function below `$this->customerSession->authenticate();` its not call customer login url  `customer/account/login`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Per @Marius Answer, Finally achieved to redirect to customer login page, while ajax.

**My Controller:**

```
    <?php
    namespace Clorida\Greetings\Controller\Index;

    use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;
    class CustomImage extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
    {
        protected $logger;
        protected $_productRepositoryFactory;
        protected $_storeManager;
        protected $customerSession;

        public function __construct(
            \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
            \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $loggerinterface,
            \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
            \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterfaceFactory $productRepositoryFactory,
            \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,

        )
        {
            parent::__construct($context);
            $this->logger = $loggerinterface;
            $this->_productRepositoryFactory = $productRepositoryFactory;
            $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
            $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
        }
        public function execute()
        {
            try {

                $this->logger->addDebug("try Block");
                if ($this->customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {

                } else {
                    $response['redirectUrl'] = $this->_url->getUrl('customer/account/login');
                    $resultJson = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_JSON);
                    $resultJson->setData($response);
                    return $resultJson;
                }

            } catch (Exception $e) {
                $this->messageManager->addError($e->getMessage());
            }

        }
    }
```

**MY ajax.js**

```
  define(["jquery"], function ($) {
      var main =
          function (config) {
              $("#finish_design_button").on("click", function () {
                  execCommand(config);
              });
          }
      function execCommand(config) {
          $.ajax({
                  method: 'POST',
                  url: config.custom_image,
                  data: { q: 'some' },
                  dataType: "json",
                  showLoader: true
              })
              .done(function( msg ) {

                  console.log("getting response");

                if(msg.redirectUrl){

                    window.location.href = msg.redirectUrl;
                }
              });
      }
      return main;
  });
```

Clear Cache, Now Works Fine.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your expectation. :).
This is how it works. You make an ajax call to a controller action. That one redirects to the customer login and sends the customer login page back. Then, the js function that handles the response from the ajax call should do something with the html for the login page. You are not telling the js callback to redirect to the login page.

You should make your controller action return a json and the js function that handles the response from the ajax call should interpret that JSON.
Instead of redirecting to the login you should send something back like `{redirect:true}`.
Then the js callback will check if `response.redirect === true` and redirect to the login page.